# C++11: how to use lambda as type parameter, where it requires a "functor type" like std::less/std::greater?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, types, functor

I'm trying to pass a type parameter to priority_queue, just like std::less or std::greater, like this:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, [](int x, int y){return x>y;})> q;
```

It doesn't compile, then I added `decltype`, still fails:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype([](int x, int y){return x>y;}))> q;
```

Question is, can we use lambda in this case, how to achieve it?

Comment: `auto comp = [](int x, int y){return x>y;}; priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)> q(comp);` Before C++20, lambda type is not default-constructible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

1. Let the compiler deduce the type of lamabda by using `decltype(lambda)`. But one thing you need to keep in mind: Prior to C++20, lambda type does not have a default constructor. As of C++20, ONLY **stateless lambda** (lambda without captures) has a default constructor, while **stateful lambda** (i.e., lambda with captures) has no default constructor (This is clearly [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) on cppreference.com). Why does the default constructor matter here? The answer is that if a default constructor exists, you don't have to pass a compare function (cmp) to the priority_queue constructor as long as you specified the lambda type as the template argument. Since the default constructor exists only for stateless lambda starting from C++20, you'd better explicitly pass a cmp argument to the constructor:

```
auto cmp = [](int x, int y){return x>y;}; 
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
```

2. Use the `<functional>` header to explicitly specify the lambda type:

```
#include <functional>
...
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, function<bool(int, int)>> q(cmp);
```

3. Use a function-obejct class. In this case, you only need to specify the function-object class as a template type argument, and you don't need to pass the cmp argument to the constructor, because your own defined function-object class has a default (synthesized) constructor.

```
struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(int x, int y) {return x > y;}
};
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, Cmp> q;
```

4. Use the library-defined function objects whenever possible.

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, std::greater<int>> q;
```

Comment: With number 4 being the most importatnt advice

Answer (score 1):

I removed the last `')'` from

`decltype([](int x, int y){return x>y;}))`

`decltype([](int x, int y){return x>y;})`

and it compiled succesfully.